Is there any support for mfc140.dll for swedish language?
We have MFC application and where there is problem with internationalization\locale. There is third party dll which creates a Edit control, upon right click, it creates a menu with ID value as ID_EDIT_PASTE, ID_EDIT_CUT, ID_EDIT_COPY,  .These are ID's are defined in the afxres.h. mfc140.dll provides the strings as "paste", "cut", "copy" for above ID's depending on the locale set in windows.
When the locale is set to swedish language for windows, we see the english strings for menu rather than swedish. I have updated the locale to French, the strings show up in French. Upon the reviewing windows\system32 folders, I don't see a resource dll for swedish which is mfc140sve.dll but there is one for french mfc140fra.dll. So where can I find this dll, is there any support for swedish language?
I was expecting the menu to be popping in the swedish language, but it was in english.

Checked on my machine and found mfc dlls only for the largest countries, and not even all of them. The 2015 redist dl page offers options only for the same countries too. However, these strings are duplicated in the executable's resource script (string-table and menus). If you can set the resources language to Swedish when you create the project, they will be OK, otherwise you will have to edit the script. As for the context menu of the edit-control of that 3rd party dll, either they will have to provide a Swedish version, or it is system-depended, so you should test it on Swedish Windows.
